# Sending data from radiobutton from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 2 activities named MainActivity and DisplayColorsActivity. The MainActivity will select the colors of the buttons that are on DisplayColorsActivity.

Sample run: I click on Green for button 1 and Red for button 2, then clicked on OK button.

MainActivity:

Select color of button 1:
oBlue
oGreen
oRed

Select color of button 2:
oBlue
oGreen
oRed

[ok button]

DisplayColorsActivity:

[return button] `//this should be color Green`
[reset button]   `//this should be color Red`

My problem is that my MainActivity doesn't go to DisplayColorsActivity when the OK button is clicked. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks!

My MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button okButton;
private RadioGroup colors;
private String color = "#0000ff";
Intent selectedColor;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    selectedColor = new Intent();

    okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOk);
    colors = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupColors1);

    colors.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.radioRed:
                    color = "#ff0000";
                    break;
                case R.id.radioBlue:
                    color = "#0000ff";
                    break;
                case R.id.radioGreen:
                    color = "#00ff00";
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayColorsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("selectedColor", color);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        }
    });
}
```

My DisplayColorsActivity.java:

```
public class DisplayColorsActivity extends Activity {

private String color = "#ff0000";
private static final  int COLOR_SELECTOR=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.colorselector);
    Button selectColorButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.returnButton);

    selectColorButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent request =new Intent(DisplayColorsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(request, COLOR_SELECTOR);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch(requestCode){
        case COLOR_SELECTOR:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                String color= data.getExtras().getString("selectedColor");
                findViewById(R.id.returnButton).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
            }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
DisplayColorsActivity shows already when I click on Ok button in  MainActivity, but it doesn't display the color I chose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second activity should be:-

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class DisplayColorsActivity extends Activity {

    private String color = "#ff0000";
    private static final  int COLOR_SELECTOR=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.colorselector);
        Button selectColorButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.returnButton);

  String color= getIntent().getExtras().getString("selectedColor");
                    selectColorButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));


 selectColorButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent request =new Intent(DisplayColorsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(request);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You need not to use startActivityForResult and on activities OnCreate() method you need to set buttons background color. Try this code and let me know

Comment: It worked! Oh one last thing, how could I remove the colors from the buttons when I click on reset?

Comment: I've figured it out already. Anyway, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Try calling `#finish` after `#setResult`

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but still it doesn't display the color